# Using maven-gae-plugin behind proxy

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, maven-gae-plugin

I'm using maven-gae-plugin 0.9.2 happily except one issue: it can not use proxy to connect to internet, and every time i call the run goal it will throw an exception:

> INFO: Unable to access
>   https://appengine.google.com/api/updatecheck?runtime=java&release=1.6.1&timestamp=1323730393&api_versions=[
>   '1.0'] java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>           at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:564)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:141)
>           at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:395)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:530)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(HttpsClient.java:272)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:329) ....

i tried use `<jvmflags>` under `<configuration>` to give my proxy address but with no luck, and Google  didn't give me any useful info too. Any ideas?

Comment: what <jvmflags> did you use? is it http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Comment: Thanks alex, problem solved, turned out to be <jvmFlags> rather than <jvmflags>, :-|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved,  `<jvmflags>` should be `<jvmFlags>`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I resolved it in other way, by putting this line in the goals of my eclipse run configuration:

```
-DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=X.X.X.X -DproxyPort=8080 appengine:update
```

I hope it could help other people with the same problem :)

Eclipse Run Configurations:
[image]